# how to enable font family and color options in tinymce editor?

Tags: javascript, fonts, tinymce

I am using a tinymce editor on my cms its having a normal text toolbar where it has bold,italic,underline, and justify option but it dont have the font family change option and not even color change. how to enable that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

i have done this in this way

```
tinyMCE.init({
theme_advanced_buttons1 : "save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
    theme_advanced_buttons2 : "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
    theme_advanced_buttons3 : "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
)};
```

Comment: This is accurate for the old edition of TinyMCE, version 3.  Any ideas for the newer version 4?

Answer (score 8):

for the upgraded version here is the full featured example

```
  tinymce.init({
    selector: 'textarea',
    height: 500,
    theme: 'modern',
    plugins: ['advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak',
    'searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen',
    'insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality',
    'emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern imagetools'
    ],
   toolbar1: 'insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image',
   toolbar2: 'print preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons',
   image_advtab: true,
   templates: [
   { title: 'Test template 1', content: 'Test 1' },
   { title: 'Test template 2', content: 'Test 2' }
   ],
   content_css: ['//fast.fonts.net/cssapi/e6dc9b99-64fe-4292-ad98-6974f93cd2a2.css',
    '//www.tinymce.com/css/codepen.min.css'
   ]
   });
```

for more reference visit https://www.tinymce.com/docs/demo/full-featured/

Answer (score 5):

In my old version of TinyMCE 4.0.10 font and color controls are added like so to tinymce.init in addition to your other init toolbar and plugin options:

```
toolbar: "styleselect fontselect fontsizeselect | forecolor backcolor",
plugins: "textcolor"
```